# Is it possible and if, how to deploy Node + Passenger app in this environment (HAProxy 1.4->Apache2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, passenger

Some might think it's a silly question but I am front end guy and I have many second thoughts.

I've developed a Node app for a customer, its pretty much ready to be put on the production server. The server is a dedicated machine which to my knowledge currently runs a high traffic Wordpress blog and a forum (also PHP + MySQL).

I've been running my app locally and on the hosting that provided build in Passenger for Node apps hosted there. I believe its a good idea to deploy with Passenger on the customer server.

I've determined that the customer server runs:

HAProxy 1.4->Varnish->Apache2

or

HAProxy 1.4->Apache2.

My knowledge ends here, I can say I have really no experience with this stuff. Passenger can run with apache and the tutorial seems pretty straight forward. Does it simply mean that all that have to be done is to:

1) install Node and Passenger (with Apache mode) on the server

2) configure Apache

3) run the app?

Is it more complicated than that? Magic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [great tutorial and video](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial#deploying_on_nginx_or_apache) about how it is done.

To summarize, they recommend that your node app has the following structure:

```
application directory
  |
  +-- app.js
  |
  +-- public/
  |
  +-- tmp/
```

Then [install the Passenger Apache Module](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download#open_source) on your server.

Then you will need to configure apache to look something like this (assuming your app is installed in `/var/www/my_awesome_app`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_awesome_app/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Be aware that passenger might not know where the proper executables are (like node).  By default, it will look in the users PATH, but if you want, you can configure that in the Apache config file like so.  If you don't know where your node is installed, try running `which node`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    PassengerNodejs /usr/sbin/node
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If your node app is using the NODE_ENV environment variable, you should note that passenger sets `NODE_ENV=production` by default.  However, you can change that to whatever you want like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    PassengerAppEnv staging
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However, as per freakin' usual, it will not work perfectly the first time.  When things don't work, tail the passenger log files and then google those errors.  This is typically located in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`. You can find out the exact location of the error log by running `passenger-config --detect-apache2`.

To tail the logs in real time, try `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`.

Little by little work through through the errors until you are victorious!

Comment: Also, when debugging, adding `PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on` to your apache virtual host block is really helpful.  It will put all the debug information in the browser.  Obviously, turn this back off when launching to the public.